# How can I ensure every us state is accounted for in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im very new to pandas

I have a CSV that contains 43 states and a count of how many times something has happened in that state.

```
STATE,Count
AL,1
AK,4
AZ,7
```

My CSV does not contain every state, how can I ensure that every state is accounted for? If its not in the original dataframe it should have a `Count` of 0.

Heres what I have so far, but its giving me `Count_x` and `Count_y` and its still not got all 50 states.

```py
# Original CSV only has 43 states
states = pd.read_csv("states.csv")

# Create a new dataframe with all states and count set to 0
all_states = [["AL", 0], ["AK", 0], ["AZ", 0], ["AR", 0], ["CA", 0], ["CO", 0], ["CT", 0], ["DE", 0], ["FL", 0], ["GA", 0], ["HI", 0], ["ID", 0], ["IL", 0], ["IN", 0], ["IA", 0], ["KS", 0], ["KY", 0], ["LA", 0], ["ME", 0], ["MD", 0], ["MA", 0], ["MI", 0], ["MN", 0], ["MS", 0], ["MO", 0], ["MT", 0], ["NE", 0], ["NV", 0], ["NH", 0], ["NJ", 0], ["NM", 0], ["NY", 0], ["NC", 0], ["ND", 0], ["OH", 0], ["OK", 0], ["OR", 0], ["PA", 0], ["RI", 0], ["SC", 0], ["SD", 0], ["TN", 0], ["TX", 0], ["UT", 0], ["VT", 0], ["VA", 0], ["WA", 0], ["WV", 0], ["WI", 0], ["WY", 0]]
all_states = pd.DataFrame(all_states, columns=["STATE", "Count"])

# Merge the two Dataframes
new_df = states.merge(all_states, on="STATE")

# Still only has 43 states
new_df
```

Notice `AK` is still missing (and a few other states)
[image: States]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are merging in the wrong direction; you need to merge `states` with `all_states`, not the other way around. Use a `left` [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then `fillna` with `0`:

```py
new_df = all_states.merge(states, on='STATE', how='left').fillna(0)
```

Note you may decide to get rid of the `Count_x` column as it will be all `0`; you can do that using `drop`:

```py
new_df.drop('Count_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thank you so much! It did turn all my counts into floating point numbers though. Well, idk if pandas considers it a floating point number but its a decimal now. Is this ezpz to fix?

Comment: Was able to revert that change with `df['Count'] = df['Count'].apply(np.int64)` thanks!

Comment: @JoeyStout sorry I wasn't around to answer your question, but yes, that is an artefact of merge. I'm glad you resolved it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try reindexing:

```
df.set_index('STATE').reindex(list(zip(*all_states))[0],fill_value = 0).reset_index()
```

Comment: This works but it resets all my `Counts` to 0

Comment: the above should only replace the missing states with 0 but keep the counts of the ones that exist